# Why does the "else" command still run after I've executed another task?

Tags: python, if-statement

My code looks like this:

```
x = input('Enter Meal (Dinner, Desert, Entre, Breakfast, Lunch, or Purify water (how to purify it)): ')
if x == "Dinner":
    print('Ingredients: 1.5kg boneless rolled pork loin, 2L boiling water, Sea-salt flakes, to season, ¼ cup extra virgin olive oil, Roast vegetables and apple sauce, to serve. Method: Preheat oven to 230°C. Untie pork and use a small, sharp knife to cut fine parallel lines into skin (in the direction you want to carve it later). Take care not to cut into the meat.Put pork, skin-side up, on a wire rack set over the sink. Pour boiling water over skin and pat dry with paper towel. This will cause the skin to shrink, exposing the score lines.Roll up and secure with 3 lengths of butcher’s twine. Rub a generous amount of salt into skin, rubbing into scores. Drizzle with ½ the oil, then massage it into skin using your hands.Put pork on a wire rack in a shallow oven tray. Bake for 20 minutes. Remove from oven and drizzle with remaining oil. Reduce temperature to 150°C and bake for a further 1 hour.Remove pork from oven and baste with a little of the pan juices. Set aside, uncovered, to rest for 15 minutes. Increase oven to 220°C. Bake for a further 10 minutes.')
if x == "Desert":
    print('Ingredients: 50g butter, chopped, 1/3 cup (70g) brown sugar, 1/4 cup (60ml) golden syrup, 1/3 cup (50g) plain flour, 1 teaspoon Masterfoods Ground Ginger, 2/3 cup (160ml) thickened cream, 2 teaspoons brandy, 1 tablespoon icing sugar mixture. Method: Preheat oven to 180°C. Line a tray with baking paper. Combine the butter, brown sugar and golden syrup in a saucepan and cook over medium heat, stirring, for 2-3 minutes or until butter melts and sugar dissolves. Set pan aside for 5 minutes to cool slightly. Add the flour and ginger to the mixture and stir to combine. Drop four teaspoonfuls of mixture on to the tray, spaced well apart. Bake for 5 minutes or until they are bubbling and have spread to 10cm in diameter. Remove from oven and allow to cool for 1 minute. Working quickly, use a palette knife to lift each one and wrap around the handle of a wooden spoon. Leave to set for 1 minute, gently slip off spoon and transfer to a wire rack. Repeat with remaining mixture. Use an electric mixer to whisk the cream, brandy and icing sugar in a small bowl until soft peaks form. Spoon cream into a piping bag fitted with a fluted nozzle. Pipe the cream among each brandy snap. Serve immediately.')
if x == "Breakfast":
    print('Ingredients: 2   Eggs, 2 tbsp.   water, 1/8 tsp. salt, pinch of pepper, 1 tsp. butter, 1/3 cup   filling, such as shredded cheese, finely chopped ham. Instructions: Beat eggs, water, salt and pepper in small bowl until blended. Heat butter in 6 to 8-inch nonstick omelet pan or skillet over medium-high heat until hot. TILT pan to coat bottom. POUR IN egg mixture. Mixture should set immediately at edges. Gently puch cooked portions from edges toward the center with inverted turner so that uncooked eggs can reach the hot pan surface. Continue cooking, tilting pan and gently moving cooked portions as needed. When top surface of eggs is thickened and no visible liquid egg remains, place filling on one side of the omelet. Fold omelet in half with turner. With a quick flip of the wrist, turn pan and invert or slide omelet onto plate. Serve immediately.')
if x == "Entre":
    print("To cook garlic bread you will need garlic bread and an oven. You can get the garlic bread from a super market (frozen,) or you can make it yourself by purchasing a frozen loaf of crusty bread, evenly spacing out cuts in the bread and putting the garlic part in the garlic bread by mixing butter, chives and garlic together. Pre heat oven too 200c and put garlic bread in for 12 to 15 mins. Carefully remove and you got some garlic bread")
else:
    print('Did not understand request, please check spelling was correct and started with a capital letter.')
```

After running the task, say dinner. I still get the message from my else command while in Thonny even though it printed the dinner task.

Why does this happen?

Comment: If `x` is not `'Entre'` it'll print `'Did not understand'`

Comment: Because you entered `Dinner`, and dinner is not `Entre`, therefore `if x == "Entre"` doesn't fire, therefore its `else` clause does. You need `elif` for all the `if` but the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else` only considers a sequence of `elif`s and one `if` statement directly before it. So your `else` only considers `"Entre"`

Try this:

```
x = input('Enter Meal (Dinner, Desert, Entre, Breakfast, Lunch, or Purify water (how to purify it)): ')
if x == "Dinner":
    print('Ingredients: 1.5kg boneless rolled pork loin, 2L boiling water, Sea-salt flakes, to season, ¼ cup extra virgin olive oil, Roast vegetables and apple sauce, to serve. Method: Preheat oven to 230°C. Untie pork and use a small, sharp knife to cut fine parallel lines into skin (in the direction you want to carve it later). Take care not to cut into the meat.Put pork, skin-side up, on a wire rack set over the sink. Pour boiling water over skin and pat dry with paper towel. This will cause the skin to shrink, exposing the score lines.Roll up and secure with 3 lengths of butcher’s twine. Rub a generous amount of salt into skin, rubbing into scores. Drizzle with ½ the oil, then massage it into skin using your hands.Put pork on a wire rack in a shallow oven tray. Bake for 20 minutes. Remove from oven and drizzle with remaining oil. Reduce temperature to 150°C and bake for a further 1 hour.Remove pork from oven and baste with a little of the pan juices. Set aside, uncovered, to rest for 15 minutes. Increase oven to 220°C. Bake for a further 10 minutes.')
elif x == "Desert":
    print('Ingredients: 50g butter, chopped, 1/3 cup (70g) brown sugar, 1/4 cup (60ml) golden syrup, 1/3 cup (50g) plain flour, 1 teaspoon Masterfoods Ground Ginger, 2/3 cup (160ml) thickened cream, 2 teaspoons brandy, 1 tablespoon icing sugar mixture. Method: Preheat oven to 180°C. Line a tray with baking paper. Combine the butter, brown sugar and golden syrup in a saucepan and cook over medium heat, stirring, for 2-3 minutes or until butter melts and sugar dissolves. Set pan aside for 5 minutes to cool slightly. Add the flour and ginger to the mixture and stir to combine. Drop four teaspoonfuls of mixture on to the tray, spaced well apart. Bake for 5 minutes or until they are bubbling and have spread to 10cm in diameter. Remove from oven and allow to cool for 1 minute. Working quickly, use a palette knife to lift each one and wrap around the handle of a wooden spoon. Leave to set for 1 minute, gently slip off spoon and transfer to a wire rack. Repeat with remaining mixture. Use an electric mixer to whisk the cream, brandy and icing sugar in a small bowl until soft peaks form. Spoon cream into a piping bag fitted with a fluted nozzle. Pipe the cream among each brandy snap. Serve immediately.')
elif x == "Breakfast":
    print('Ingredients: 2   Eggs, 2 tbsp.   water, 1/8 tsp. salt, pinch of pepper, 1 tsp. butter, 1/3 cup   filling, such as shredded cheese, finely chopped ham. Instructions: Beat eggs, water, salt and pepper in small bowl until blended. Heat butter in 6 to 8-inch nonstick omelet pan or skillet over medium-high heat until hot. TILT pan to coat bottom. POUR IN egg mixture. Mixture should set immediately at edges. Gently puch cooked portions from edges toward the center with inverted turner so that uncooked eggs can reach the hot pan surface. Continue cooking, tilting pan and gently moving cooked portions as needed. When top surface of eggs is thickened and no visible liquid egg remains, place filling on one side of the omelet. Fold omelet in half with turner. With a quick flip of the wrist, turn pan and invert or slide omelet onto plate. Serve immediately.')
elif x == "Entre":
    print("To cook garlic bread you will need garlic bread and an oven. You can get the garlic bread from a super market (frozen,) or you can make it yourself by purchasing a frozen loaf of crusty bread, evenly spacing out cuts in the bread and putting the garlic part in the garlic bread by mixing butter, chives and garlic together. Pre heat oven too 200c and put garlic bread in for 12 to 15 mins. Carefully remove and you got some garlic bread")
else:
    print('Did not understand request, please check spelling was correct and started with a capital letter.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else:` block is only `else` to the `if` statement directly preceding it, so in this case, becuase your input `x != "Entre"`, that `if` block is not evaluated, and the code jumps straight to the `else`. If you want the `else` to only run if *none* of the if statements have evaulated to True, you should chain `elif`s like this:

```
x = input('Enter Meal (Dinner, Desert, Entre, Breakfast, Lunch, or Purify water (how to purify it)): ')
if x == "Dinner":
    print('Ingredients: 1.5kg boneless rolled pork loin, 2L boiling water, Sea-salt flakes, to season, ¼ cup extra virgin olive oil, Roast vegetables and apple sauce, to serve. Method: Preheat oven to 230°C. Untie pork and use a small, sharp knife to cut fine parallel lines into skin (in the direction you want to carve it later). Take care not to cut into the meat.Put pork, skin-side up, on a wire rack set over the sink. Pour boiling water over skin and pat dry with paper towel. This will cause the skin to shrink, exposing the score lines.Roll up and secure with 3 lengths of butcher’s twine. Rub a generous amount of salt into skin, rubbing into scores. Drizzle with ½ the oil, then massage it into skin using your hands.Put pork on a wire rack in a shallow oven tray. Bake for 20 minutes. Remove from oven and drizzle with remaining oil. Reduce temperature to 150°C and bake for a further 1 hour.Remove pork from oven and baste with a little of the pan juices. Set aside, uncovered, to rest for 15 minutes. Increase oven to 220°C. Bake for a further 10 minutes.')
elif x == "Desert":
    print('Ingredients: 50g butter, chopped, 1/3 cup (70g) brown sugar, 1/4 cup (60ml) golden syrup, 1/3 cup (50g) plain flour, 1 teaspoon Masterfoods Ground Ginger, 2/3 cup (160ml) thickened cream, 2 teaspoons brandy, 1 tablespoon icing sugar mixture. Method: Preheat oven to 180°C. Line a tray with baking paper. Combine the butter, brown sugar and golden syrup in a saucepan and cook over medium heat, stirring, for 2-3 minutes or until butter melts and sugar dissolves. Set pan aside for 5 minutes to cool slightly. Add the flour and ginger to the mixture and stir to combine. Drop four teaspoonfuls of mixture on to the tray, spaced well apart. Bake for 5 minutes or until they are bubbling and have spread to 10cm in diameter. Remove from oven and allow to cool for 1 minute. Working quickly, use a palette knife to lift each one and wrap around the handle of a wooden spoon. Leave to set for 1 minute, gently slip off spoon and transfer to a wire rack. Repeat with remaining mixture. Use an electric mixer to whisk the cream, brandy and icing sugar in a small bowl until soft peaks form. Spoon cream into a piping bag fitted with a fluted nozzle. Pipe the cream among each brandy snap. Serve immediately.')
elif x == "Breakfast":
    print('Ingredients: 2   Eggs, 2 tbsp.   water, 1/8 tsp. salt, pinch of pepper, 1 tsp. butter, 1/3 cup   filling, such as shredded cheese, finely chopped ham. Instructions: Beat eggs, water, salt and pepper in small bowl until blended. Heat butter in 6 to 8-inch nonstick omelet pan or skillet over medium-high heat until hot. TILT pan to coat bottom. POUR IN egg mixture. Mixture should set immediately at edges. Gently puch cooked portions from edges toward the center with inverted turner so that uncooked eggs can reach the hot pan surface. Continue cooking, tilting pan and gently moving cooked portions as needed. When top surface of eggs is thickened and no visible liquid egg remains, place filling on one side of the omelet. Fold omelet in half with turner. With a quick flip of the wrist, turn pan and invert or slide omelet onto plate. Serve immediately.')
elif x == "Entre":
    print("To cook garlic bread you will need garlic bread and an oven. You can get the garlic bread from a super market (frozen,) or you can make it yourself by purchasing a frozen loaf of crusty bread, evenly spacing out cuts in the bread and putting the garlic part in the garlic bread by mixing butter, chives and garlic together. Pre heat oven too 200c and put garlic bread in for 12 to 15 mins. Carefully remove and you got some garlic bread")
else:
    print('Did not understand request, please check spelling was correct and started with a capital letter.')
```

I would also suggest `lower()`ing your `x` variable, and checking against an all lowercase version of your text, i.e.

```
if x.lower() == "dinner":
```

this way, the user can enter `"dinner"` or `"Dinner"` or `"DiNnEr"` and they'll all evaluate to `"dinner"`